# Validating Post Json Data Spring Boot

Tags: json, spring-boot, postman

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"application/json"})
public Alien addDetails(@RequestBody Alien alien){
return repo.save(alien);
}
```

Alien.java

```
@Entity

public class Alien{
@Id
private int id;
private String name;
private String planet;
Getter and setter
```

Now I want to validate the post json data before saving it to the database.
If any of the field is empty then the controller should return an error.
For example

`{"id": 1, "name": "Alien1", "planet":"Mars" }`

This is acceptable json data
But if there is any field is missing such as

`{"name": "Alien1", "planet":"Mars" }`

Then the controller should return an error and not creating the instance of Alien

I tried with @Valid @NotNull still the controller creates an empty instance of Alien and save to the database.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should add spring boot validation dependency into your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And then add annotations like @NotBlank or @NotEmpty to verify if a value is assigned to that field or not. Those annotations should be on the top of your entity's attributes which you want to validate them.For example:

```
public class Alien{
  @NotBlank(message="Name is mandatory")
  private String name;
}
```

Finally, add @Valid annotation into your controller method like:

```
public Alien addDetails(@Valid @RequestBody Alien alien){
 return repo.save(alien);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `@Validated` annotation to your controller to make `@Valid` annotation do the work. You should also annotate fields in your `Entity` with constraints.

I.e., `name` could be `@NotBlank`.

And yes, make sure that you have imported:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Edit:
In Controller, you should not accept `Entity` as a body. Instead, you should create a DTO object and then map it to the `Entity` in the service. You should also put validation constraints on the DTO!